# MySQL Query from version 5.1 is not working in 5.7

Tags: mysql

```
select * from batches join (
                  select * from (
                      select *, row_number() over (
                          partition by batch_id
                          order by date ASC
                      ) as row_num
                      from batch_schedule where display = 'Yes'
                  ) as d_schedule
                  where d_schedule.row_num = 1
              )
              as f_schedule
              on batches.id = f_schedule.batch_id
              WHERE (f_schedule.date BETWEEN '2021/03/01' AND '2021/04/30')
```

This query is working fine in version 5.1 but not working in 5.7

What I am trying to achieve is,
filtering batches based on batch_schedule start dates.

I need to select the 1st row from the right table with condition display = 'Yes' and order by date asc and based on that row value i need to display batches.

I am getting the below error message

```
select is not valid at this position for this server version expecting '(' with
```

Comment: What you are trying to do and what error you get?

Comment: _'not working'_ is not a problem description. Describe what is happening, what you expect to happen, and include the full text of any error messages you see.

Comment: I am doing date range filtering. I need to display a list of batches based on batch_schedule start dates.
One batch has multiple dates.
I need to check only the first row in the batch_schedule table also before I check I need to order by date asc.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the space between `over` and `(` ?

Comment: That query cannot work in MySQL 5.1 or 5.7. It uses window functions, which are not supported until MySQL 8.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from batches join ( SELECT * from batch_schedule 
where display = 'Yes' group by batch_id order by date asc ) 
as f_schedule on batches.id = f_schedule.batch_id 
where(f_schedule.date BETWEEN '2021/03/01' AND '2021/04/30');
```

I tried this and it works.
I am posting here in case if someone looking for the same thing it will help.